# Alter the style of all cells with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl 2.0.3 with python2.7.

Is there a way to apply a style to every cell in a worksheet? Lets say I want to change the font of all cells, similar to how I would open an excel document, hit ctrl+a, right click and change the format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no method to do this. At the moment the best approach would probably be to set the style for all the relevant columns or rows

```
style = Style(…)
for col in 'ABCD':
     ws._styles[col] = style
```

I think we'll be working on improving handling styles in coming releases.

Comment: Note: ws._styles should index "col" instead of "A"

Comment: Well?! The question certainly remains relevant: How to apply a style to every cell in a worksheet. In fact, yesterday I was looking for an answer to exactly that question. Also, it is conceivable that somebody, even today, would have a similar software setup. Conclusion: The note does not hurt.

Comment: The note relies on private API which is no longer available and would never have really worked anyway because of the way styles for rows and columns are implemented in OOXML.

Comment: SOLVED: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195113/4539999

Answer (score 6):

**Updated:** The comments show `DEFAULT_FONT` class can now be imported and the properties set directly before saving workbook:

```py
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import DEFAULT_FONT
wb = Workbook()
wb.active['B3'] = "Hello"
DEFAULT_FONT.name = "Arial"
wb.save("DemoDefaultFont.xlsx")
```

More is needed to set multiple properties simultaneously. Copy the properties from a temporary `Font` object:

```py
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import DEFAULT_FONT
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = Workbook()
wb.active['B3'] = "Hello"
_font = Font(name="Arial", sz=10, b=True)
{k: setattr(DEFAULT_FONT, k, v) for k, v in _font.__dict__.items()}
wb.save("DemoDefaultFont.xlsx")
```

Further details: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/fonts.html?highlight=default_font

Comment: How about importing `DEFAULT_FONT` and alter it with something like `DEFAULT_FONT.name = "Arial"`? I just did it, it works (openpyxl 3.0.7, Python 3.6).

Comment: The above import didn't work for me on OpenPyXL 3.0.7, Python 3.9.7. I've had success using `from openpyxl.styles import DEFAULT_FONT`. Afterword, changing values was a cinch.  E.g. `DEFAULT_FONT.size = 11`

Comment: Updated answer to change `DEFAULT_FONT`, hack no longer required

Comment: The first example does not work for me on MacOS with Python 3.11.4, openpyxl==3.1.2.  The second example does work