# How to change font size in Python OpenPyXL

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do I change the font size of a cell? I am using OpenPyXL.

It will not let me send this question without typing the above with perfect grammar and spelling, so the last few words people should know what I mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting styles in Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440284/setting-styles-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font
fontStyle = Font(size = "10")
ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1, value = 'Test Text').font = fontStyle
```

I'm using openpyxl version: 2.3.2

Comment: A lot of effort to maintain on a sheet rather than change the default font: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195113/4539999

Answer (score 4):

## openpyxl > 3.0 (2021)

In openpyxl handling styles changes a bit between the version.

The current version (as of writing 3.0.6) handles font object as immutable and has deprecated the `font.copy(...)` function.

Therefore the only way I figured out **only** change the font size (and keep the rest as it is) is:

`ws.cell(1, 1).font += Font(size=new_font_size-ws.cell(1, 1).font)`

### Explained

Font is an [`openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable.Serialisable`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable.html#openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable.Serialisable) object for which that add operator is implemented and recommended by the

> DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function copy (Use copy(obj) or cell.obj = cell.obj + other).

Only Problem is that, using the `__add__` operator will add the given font size with the original one. Therefore the original one has to be subtracted.

### Full Example with Function

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook, worksheet, cell
from openpyxl.styles import Font

def change_fontsize(cell: cell, fontsize: float):
    orig_size = cell.font.size
    cell.font += Font(size=fontsize - orig_size)

input_filename = "to_modify.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(input_filename)
# Get first sheet
sh: worksheet = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
change_fontsize(sh.cell(1,1), 5)
wb.save('modified.xlsx')
```

### Stability Note

As this functionality is not really documented in openpyxl I assume that one can't assume that this will be stable.
Currently it works only because of the implementation of the default values of Fonts `__init__` function, which all evaluate `False`.

Comment: In openpyxl 3.0.7, cells default size value is given with "cell.font.sz". Had to check for not None before setting the substraction

Answer (score 1):

This code opens a *.xlsx file and edits the style of cell 'A1' so it has font size 20. I newer versions of openpyxl you get an error message if you try to overwrite the font directly.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

path = 'filename.xlsx'
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws, *ows = book
ws['A1'].font = Font(size=20)
book.save(path)
```

The *ows will place any other sheets then the first inside a list, if there is only one worksheet the list will be empty. (ows=[])

Answer (score -3):

Openpyxl styling can achieve this for you!

```
cell.style.font.size = "font size goes here as integer"
```

Comment: That didnt work. I have a worksheet names ws. And I want to make the font in a specific cell bigger. What would the actual line of code for that look like. For example would it be something like ws['A2'].cell.font.size = "5"?

Comment: Obviously the exact code that I wrote isn't going to work.. it's a general example from docs... I am not going to write the code for you. That's not what Stackoverflow is for.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'font'`, so no.